# How do I draw 2D primtives to a SurfaceView that's a submember of my layout?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm just learning Android and Java. I'm familiar with graphics and programming in general in other languages.

I have a simple layout with some buttons, text views, and a SurfaceView all inside a RelativeLayout like this:

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quit"
        android:id="@+id/buttonShutdown"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="shutdown"/>
    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonShutdown"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Then I have a simple MainActivity.java which is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    SurfaceView surfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.getSurface();
     }

    protected void shutdown(View view)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Obviously there's a little more to my code because I have a couple buttons and a couple textviews, but the point is I have a layout with several widgets and the SurfaceView is just one of them.

I've seen a number of examples of drawing to a surface view but they all seem to take over the whole screen and stuff.

How can I simply draw 2D lines and stuff to my SurfaceView as is without obliterating the rest of my code or layout widgets?

I've been working for days on this and it has never taken me this much effort in any other language/framework to simply draw some 2D lines!

I would be most grateful for any working examples that work *with* my existing layout.

UPDATE:

To clarify, the problem I'm having trouble with is how to get a handle on the surfaceView in order to get a handler in order to get a canvas on it. Once I get a canvas interface then I can lock, draw, and unlock. But I cannot figure out how to get the Canvas attached to the surfaceView.

UPDATE:

I think I have a holder for the surface view now, but how do I Get the canvas for it?

Thank you very much,

Jesse

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question, what I understood is that you are trying to make a side panel where you will include control buttons and rest of the screen is used for custom drawing, am I correct?

Comment: Harshiv, you're partly correct - I do have control buttons and informational text views around the outside of the SurfaceView and they are all siblings with the SurfaceView in a RelativeLayout. The SurfaceView could take up all the rest but that's not the point. It's a sibling to the other items, and I want to draw colored 2D lines into it, probably from another thread but that too may be besides the point. Thanks very much, Jesse

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is : you check the touch Coordinates in `onTouch` (Event.ACTION_MOVE or something like that,)method,  `if` they are in the surfaceView area, then draw them  `else` return.

Comment: I'm generating my 2D coordinates from other mathematical sources. I'll update my question to clarify that I'm trying to figure out how to get a handle on my surfaceView SurfaceView so I can get a handler and get a canvas. Thanks! Jesse

Comment: Do you really need a SurfaceView? For almost all uses, overriding `onDraw()` in a custom View and drawing directly on the canvas is enough. A SurfaceView is useful only for more complicated stuff (e.g. a game engine with a dedicated render thread).

Comment: Dalmas, thanks for the note. I do ultimately intend to have a dedicated render thread and update the scene at 30fps, and the Android documentation said that SurfaceView was the way to go. But I'd be delighted to try anything better you might suggest! Thanks, Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after much hair pulling I got it working.

Now please a note to you grownups out there: this is intended to be a very very simple educational demonstration of the minimal code to draw lines on the screen in a Surface View. I also know that holder.getSurface(); takes some time to come alive and so drawing cannot happen right away. That's why it's in an onClick. I also know that SurfaceView rendering should be done from its own thread, and that it should be set up with 3 callbacks.

This is just a simple sample so please do not flame me for not writing the ideal fully fledged app! Thank you kindly.

My MainActivity.java:

```
package com.gladeworks.gwscope ;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView = null;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Press the Draw button!");
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.getSurface();
        paint = new Paint();

        final Button buttonDraw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDraw);
        buttonDraw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                draw(view);
            }
        });
    }


    protected void draw(View view)  //This gets called when the Draw button is clicked.
    {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas == null) {
            textView.setText("Canvas is still null");
        } else {
            canvas.drawRGB(32, 32, 255);    //Clear the canvas to light blue
            canvas.drawLine(0,0,1000,1000,paint);//Draw a line from top left corner down and right.
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            textView.setText("Done drawing!");
        }


    }

}
```

And here's my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gladeworks.gwscope.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Uninitialized"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonExit"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quit"
        android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDraw"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonDraw"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonDraw"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Draw"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDraw"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Things to improve:
The line drawing code should really be in its own thread so it doesn't block the user interface thread.
The labels for buttons and stuff should really be defined int he resources file for easier translation efforts.
The canvas and SurfaceView shuold be set up with callbacks for dealing with Creation, Change, and Destruction.

But this should provide a clear path to beginners for understanding the needed sequence of steps to draw line graphics to a SurfaceView.

Comment: If you want to make a tutorial for others, make sure you understand https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity , especially if you add a separate thread. SurfaceView is very different from other Views. In most cases you're better off using a custom View (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) -- they're simpler, and rendering through a Canvas can be hardware accelerated.

Comment: Thanks Fadden - What approach would you suggest for a 30/60fps realtime rendering setup, like an oscilloscope or game? Is something other than a SurfaceView better for that? Thanks! Jesse

Comment: Use a custom View if you want to use Canvas, use a SurfaceView if you want to use OpenGL ES. The latter can be considerably faster, but GLES has a steep learning curve. If you're interested in writing an app, rather than a graphics engine, I'd recommend using an open-source graphics engine, or one of the game engines.